# How to use retract/retractall along side assertz in pyswip

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I am facing buffered facts issue, where assertz(facts) from previous query also remains in buffer in subsequent querying.

I found [retract](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=retract/1) removes facts from database but still could not figure out how to use them in python(/pyswip).

Any example or reference much appreciable.

code snippet:

```
        self.prolog_question_identify = Prolog()
        self.prolog_question_identify.consult(subject_object.pro")
        for linking in self.post_script_link_list:
            linkage = self.outObj.createLinkage(linking,len(link.links)) #UDF in preprocess_link_output
            self.prolog_question_identify.assertz(linkage)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, retract can help you to remove the facts from databse.

```
    for p in self.prolog_question_identify.query("retract(linkage(_,_,_)),fail"):
        print
```

in `linkage` you can give which ever value you want to flush out.